# How to call remote EJB from standalone client

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee

I have my EJB deployed on weblogic server. I want to access those EJB from standalone applications (a thin client).

Answer (score 20):

Ok... I found it myself. :)

Here is code that I used to connect to Remote EJB from thin client.

```
 Hashtable env = new Hashtable(5);
 env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
 //Assuming weblogic server is running on localhost at port 7001
 env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");

 Context ic = new InitialContext(env);

 //obtain a reference to the home or local home interface
 FooHome fooHome = (FooHome)ic.lookup("MyBeans/FooHome");

 //Get a reference to an object that implements the beans remote (component) interface
 Foo foo = fooHome.create();

 //call the service exposed by the bean
 foo.shoutFoo()
```

And it worked me.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if this is what worked for you.

Comment: If you use a `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory`it means that you must call your EJB only from a client grabbing some weblogic libraries, wich is probably not that thin.

Comment: you should close the initial context in a finally block

Comment: The above code i'm running from command line java program (public static void main), i'm getting below error. Please suggest.

Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory