# Oracle ADF with EJB3 client

Tags: client, ejb-3.0, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I have pointer (JNDI) to EJB3 service which was created on other side of communication channel. Or in other words it was created on our customers application server.
Now I need to do ADF based interface for invoke that EJB3.
I'm having no problems with interface but I'm struggling with how to call EJB3.
Should I do it in my backing bean like it's made by client:

```
public class SessionEJBClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final Context context = getInitialContext();
            SessionEJB sessionEJB = (SessionEJB)context.lookup("MyApp-SessionEJB#org.test.SessionEJB");
        } catch (CommunicationException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println(ex.getRootCause().getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("\n*** A CommunicationException was raised.  This typically\n*** occurs when the target WebLogic server is not running.\n");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        // WebLogic Server 10.x connection details
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://serverhost:serverport");
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }
}
```

Or is there any other way of doing it? Or in other words what is the proper way of reference and invoke remote EJB3?

10x

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "and respect the MVC pattern", then overriding an Entity Object and accessing the EJB from there seems the best way. Then a VO built on top of it could give you the "normal" ADF BC Layer - then you create an Application Module and it is exposed as a Data Control and you can declaratively build your page on top of that. However,the ADFBC layer is probably too thick for your needs.

So...if you don't want to use ADF BC, you can create a Stateless Session bean (again in the Model Layer) to act as a Facade around the EJB and delegate calls to it. The benefit in both cases is the separation of Business Logic (the EJB I assume?) from the View layers, and in ADF you can create a Data Control from the ADF BC or Session Bean layer and use this as the basis for ADF Faces pages.

Comment: This is all ok, but I need one example how to call remote EJB3 or in other words how to invoke remote EJB3. I need example.

Comment: is this what you mean?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293835/how-to-call-remote-ejb-from-standalone-client, or this?http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25741/EJB-3-0-Remote-Session-Bean-Lookup - this has nothing to do with ADF _ it's standard JEE

Answer (score 0):

ADF can work on top of POJOs or Session EJBs.
So you would write a Java layer that calls the EJB - then you will expose that Java layer as an ADF data control and then you can drag and drop your way to create ADF UIs.
http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/2009/07/java_class_data_control_and_ad.html
http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/2009/01/insert_update_for_jpaejb_30_wi.html

Or if you rather skip the ADF binding layer you can write managed beans that will call the EJB and then bind the ADF UI directly to those beans.